# move something with javascript and make it moving slower

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I've got a homework and cant solve it. We have to make a Heart moving in a random direction by mouseover. Like in real world it should then get slower in moving.

I tried to realize this with a setInterval, but I cant decrease the Interval and so it is not slowing down. Here is my code, maybe someone can help:

### script.js

```
var xpos = 130;
var ypos = 150;
var id1;
var velocity = 1000;
var xstart=5;
var ystart=57;
var xend=8+800-225;
var yend=100+400-125;
var dx = 1;
var dy = 2;
var time = 100;
var add = 0;
var running;

function move(){
    clearInterval(id1);
    var rand1 = Math.random();
    var rand2 = Math.random();

    if(rand1 < 0)
        dx=-dx;

    if(rand2 < 0)
        dy=-dy;
}

function speed(t){
    var id1 = setInterval(function(){
        if(xpos+dx > xend || xpos+dx < xstart)
            dx=-dx;
        if(ypos+dy > yend || ypos+dy < ystart)
            dy=-dy;       
        xpos += dx;
        ypos += dy;
        the_node = document.getElementById('heart');
        the_node.innerHTML = '<div class="blue" style="position:absolute;top:' + ypos + 'pt;left:' + xpos + 'pt;" onmouseover="move();">&hearts;</div>'
        t = add;
        add+=50; 
        console.log(t, add);
        stop();
    },t);
}
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .grey {background-color: #eeeeee; 
            width: 400px; 
            height: 200px;}
        .blue {color: red;
                font-size: 30px;}
        #fang {
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Fang das Herz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hausaufgabe: Fang das Herz</h1>
    <div class="grey">
        <div id="heart">
        <div class="blue" style="position:absolute; top:150px; left:130px;" onmouseover="move();">&hearts;</div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so far!

Comment: Instead of `setInterval` you can try calling `setTimeout` at each step, increasing the delay.

Comment: given the code in your `move` function, there are more problems: your problem statement says nothing about changing directions while moving, and you clearly didn't look up what `Math.random()` does, because it yields a number between 0 and 1, so your `if` statements are *never* going to evaluate true.

Comment: @Oriol do you mean that I should put the stuff of setInterval in a inner setTimeout and within that increase the delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to move over time, literally do that. I won't be doing your homework for you, but I will give you the outline so you can then figure out how to program that:

```
- determine how many milliseconds MS you want the thing to move for (universal)
- determine the starting speed to move in (universal)
on mouseover:
  - determine the current object position (x,y)
  - determine the speed and direction of travel (dx,dy) for the object
  - record the mouseover start time for this object
  call update.
```

with as update function:

```
update:
  - determine the current acceleration A as: map "now" from (start,start+MS) to (1,0).
  - determine the object's new position (x + A*dx, y + A*dx)
  - update (x,y) to be these new values
  if (f > 0):
    schedule a next call to update some time in the future.
```

This is the kind of "don't immediately start programming" analysis you do before you sit down to program the actual code, because this way, you now know what all the bits of your code should do before you implement them, and it'll be much easier to spot when something doesn't work (because you already know how it's supposed to work at each step).

Comment: thanks Mike, that is a good approach. I am not able to determine the current position of the object. It says "Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null". :(

Comment: Mike, could you please help me a little bit more? For sure its not about getting my homework done by someone else but I really dont get anybit further. The points you mentioned make absolut sense, but I cant  get it in code

Comment: if you get the error cited, it means you're calling this code before the object you're querySelecting actually exist. Make sure to wait for the DOM to be ready. In this case, move that `<script.....></script>` to just before `</body>` so it runs after your DOM's all but finalised.